# What do we want to do about "How do I program" questions?

Tags: discussion

A lot of people move into test automation from a manual testing background and, as such, get stuck on Programming 101-type questions, like "[How do I use conditionals](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12843/how-to-click-on-element-only-if-data-exists-in-excel-table/12853#12853)". Do they belong here? I believe they are SO questions, but I suspect they'd be closed if we migrated them for being too basic...

Comment: Do you think they'd be closed because they're too easy, or because OP appears to be lazy?

Comment: Either or both. It's been a while since I frequented SO but IIRC they don't take kindly do "How do I use conditionals" type questions

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265565/downvoting-stupid-simple-questions

Comment: They're also almost certainly duplicates, so if nothing else, that'd get them closed and thus the migration rejected.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22957/sqa-cleanup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the answer. We check SO for a duplicate answer, and if we find one, we mark the SQA question as a dup with a reference to that SO answer.  If we don't find a dup, we migrate them to SO and hope that it's answered there.

Comment: If we know it's going to be closed as a dupe on SO then we should not migrate. We should simply link and close from here. There's already over 8000 questions on SO that need close-vote attention, we don't need to add fuel to the fire. We've talked about this in TL before, it's poor etiquette to send something you think has a high chance of being closed.

Comment: Thanks.  I updated my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: I don't think we can mark them as cross-site duplicates? But we can migrate and let them close, it doesn't count as a failed migration if the close reason is "duplicate". It's not the most polite thing, but I don't see much other option in the tooling.

Comment: That's true, but as @corsiKa pointed out, SO is already overwhelmed with questions that need close-vote attention, so we need to find a different approach.

Comment: @Yamikuronue I will catch a lot of hell in TL (the mod chat) if I migrate questions they just have to close anyway. They'll probably say something like "You have 50k SO rep and can't tell when a question needed to just be closed? GTFO."

Comment: @corsiKa So how do we close as a duplicate of a question on another site? Last I checked, it's not technically possible.

Comment: I would close as Off Topic, with a custom reason of "low quality programming problem" or something similarly appropriate.